# How to stop/play video in recyclerlistview when it scrolls into or out of frame

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, recyclerlistview

I am experimenting trying to create a TikTok style swipe in Expo React Native. I am using recylerlistview with paging enabled which works well. And I am using a json file to simulate loading more data as you reach the end of the scroll. I am stuck on a few things though.

1. I only want the current + next video to actually load. Even if my windows size is 5 I don't want to be loading that many videos.
2. I want videos to play once they are visible, and videos to stop as soon as they are not.

I have tried playing with indexes but my knowledge falls short here. Just looking for some pointers and maybe an example to help me learn.

Here is a snack to play with: https://snack.expo.io/@buzzcore/e3667a

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think checking which item (or index) is in view is the way to go. In your example you have `onVisibleIndexesChanged`, check you're version cause the docs say it's deperecated since 2.0 beta, so maybe use `onVisibleIndicesChanged`.

Comment: For play/pause https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview/issues/149
and for rendering `renderAheadOffset` will be used